# D3 - ticks wrong positioned

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I tried now couple of things but I can not figure out why my ticks are wrong positioned. I used different sources to make this stacked barchart.

Here is the fiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/azj7guec/

And here is the code itself:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .50);
        y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
        z = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["darkblue", "blue", "lightblue"])


        console.log("RAW MATRIX---------------------------");
    // 4 columns: ID,c1,c2,c3
        var matrix = [
            [22,45,34,65],
            [23,66,12,22],
            [24,32,44,76],
            [25,12,76,32],
            [26, 67, 34, 56]
            ];
        console.log(matrix)
        var keys = matrix.map(function(item){return item[0]});

        console.log("REMAP---------------------------");
        var remapped =["c1","c2","c3"].map(function(dat,i){
            return matrix.map(function(d,ii){
                return {x: d[0], y: d[i+1] };
            })
        });
        console.log(remapped)

        console.log("LAYOUT---------------------------");
        var stacked = d3.layout.stack()(remapped)
        console.log(stacked)

        //var yMax= d3.max(stacked)

        x.domain(keys);
        y.domain([0, d3.max(stacked[stacked.length - 1], function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);

        // show the domains of the scales
        console.log("x.domain(): " + x.domain())
        console.log("y.domain(): " + y.domain())
        console.log("------------------------------------------------------------------");

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .ticks(10)

            .orient("left");

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .tickValues(keys)
            .orient("bottom");

   var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

     svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
     .selectAll("text")  
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", ".15em")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "rotate(-65)" 
        });


svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Open Issues");

        // Add a group for each column.
        var valgroup = svg.selectAll("g.valgroup")
        .data(stacked)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "valgroup")
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); })
        .style("stroke", function(d, i) { return d3.rgb(z(i)).darker(); });

        // Add a rect for each date.
        var rect = valgroup.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function(d){return d;})
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("width", 20)
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); });
        //.attr("width", x.rangeBand());
```

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: You need to offset the positions of the bars by the width of the x axis bands -- http://jsfiddle.net/azj7guec/1/

Comment: This works. I am taking my first steps with d3. This is something I did not know before. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ordinal scale divides its output range into intervals based on the input domain. Your current positioning puts the bars at the beginning of those intervals, whereas the ticks are in the center. To match up the positions, add half the interval minus half the bar width to the beginning of the interval:

```
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x) + (x.rangeBand() - 20) / 2; })
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/azj7guec/1/).